# Apex test class not working and fails

Tags: apex, code-coverage, failing-tests, code, apextestrunresult

I have the following apex class:

```
public with sharing class TT_DisplayRelatedOpportunities {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Opportunity> getOppList(String recordId) {
        return [
            SELECT Name
            FROM Opportunity
            WHERE LOT__c =: recordId OR Lot_2__c =: recordId
        ];
    }
}
```

I created the following test class for it but it fails and results in 0% coverage.

```
@isTest
public class TT_DisplayRelatedOpportunitiesTest {
    @isTest
    static void testGetOppList() {
        // Test data setup
        List<Opportunity> opportunities = new List<Opportunity>{
            new Opportunity(Name = 'Opportunity 1', LOT__c = 'TestRecordId'),
            new Opportunity(Name = 'Opportunity 2', LOT__c = 'AnotherTestRecordId'),
            new Opportunity(Name = 'Opportunity 3', Lot_2__c = 'TestRecordId'),
            new Opportunity(Name = 'Opportunity 4', Lot_2__c = 'DifferentRecordId')
        };
        insert opportunities;

        // Call the method to test
        List<Opportunity> result = TT_DisplayRelatedOpportunities.getOppList('TestRecordId');

        // Assert the results
        Set<Id> expectedIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Opportunity opp : opportunities) {
            if (opp.LOT__c == 'TestRecordId' || opp.Lot_2__c == 'TestRecordId') {
                expectedIds.add(opp.Id);
            }
        }

        Set<Id> actualIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Opportunity opp : result) {
            actualIds.add(opp.Id);
        }

        System.assertEquals(expectedIds, actualIds, 'Incorrect or incomplete list of opportunities.');
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you generating the TestRecordId and DifferentRecordId? Are they records in the org? If so, then you'd need to annotate the class to read all data. Better approach would be to create the records for Lot__c and Lot2__c.

Comment: Also, I'm sure you're missing a few mandatory fields on Opportunity. I can recall StageName, CloseDate etc are mandatory and not filling them will fail the DML. It would help if you can provide the error message seen.

Comment: Check the debug log when running the test class. As @Apex Srinivas said some required fields are missing of opportunities while test data creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test opportunities you are inserting do not have their required fields populated. Every Opportunity needs a `Name`, `StageName` and `CloseDate`. E.g:

```
new Opportunity(Name = 'Opportunity 1', StageName = 'Prospecting', CloseDate = Date.today(), LOT__c = 'TestRecordId'),
```

Comment: _"Second, in your assertEquals you are comparing two Sets. This is not possible as it will be comparing the reference to the Set itself rather than the elements in the Set."_ This is incorrect. Assertions can be made against sets (and lists, and maps). You can verify this for yourself by running the following one-liner as anonymous apex: `System.assertEquals(new Set<Id>{'001000000000001', '001000000000002'}, new Set<Id>{'001000000000001', '001000000000002'}, 'Set comparison failed');` Also works with `Assert.areEqual()`.

Comment: Further illustrating, another one-liner that does fail as expected: `Assert.areEqual(new Set<Id>{'001000000000001', '001000000000002'}, new Set<Id>{'001000000000001', '001000000000003'}, 'Set comparison failed');`

Comment: Thanks I have removed that bit